# django - database design - mutiple tables require 1+ phone_number(s)

Tags: django-models

Question regarding how to setup dbase relationships (newbie, this may be trivial)

Followed the django tutorial (Poll, Choices); understood that 1 Poll has many Choice(s), therefore many Choice(s) point to a single Poll.

```
   class Poll(models.Model):
      question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      ...

   class Choice(models.Model):
      poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
      ...
```

Question:
I have a database with places, persons, etc. (mutiple tables). 
A subset of my tables have a similar field. 
I want a place  to have 1+ phone_number(s). 
I want a person to have 1+ phone_number(s). 
I may want other tables to have 1+ phone_number(s).

If I followed the Poll/Choice approach, then my problem is indicated by the question marks shown below under PhoneNumber.

```
   class Person(models.Model):
      firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      ...

   class Place(models.Model):
      description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      ...

   class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
      ??? = models.ForeignKey(???)
      ...
```

I have considered using inheritance so that both Person and Place inherit from the same base class.  But I may have other fields besides phone_number for which I have a similar situation, and which span a different subset of tables. E.g.

```
               phone_number(s)     comments
               ---------------     --------
Person         yes                 no
Place          yes                 yes
Contract       no                  yes
...
```

Any advice on how to correctly design these types of relationships would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Generic Relations](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/). [Also here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

Comment: cool, if it remains unclear to you, you can update your question and let us know where you're stumbling.

Comment: hasen, i read the docs, used the generic relations approach, and it solved my problem. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

check [ContenType](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#ref-contrib-contenttypes) app, and specifically [Generic Relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1).  basically, you store both the type and id of the person/place object on the PhoneNumber object.

Comment: as with the first answer, thank you for the reply - I am reading the  ContentType documentation.